# How can I pass my LinQ generated data from a controller to my secondary View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm having a small problem as I'm not sure how to pass data that I generated in my controller to my View.

I have a View1 that has input fields after I submit this form the strings go into my controller where they are parsed to DateTime and using LINQ I get the data from my database that fits the criteria. And I want to pass this generated data to a View so that I can write it out.

Not sure if my logic is incorrect or am I missing something.

**My form view:**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "ViewMovies";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Select date range for movies</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ViewMovies", "ViewMovies"))
{
<input type="text" name="dateFrom" />
<input type="text" name="dateTo" />
<input type="submit" />
}
```

**My Controller:**

```
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public ViewMoviesController()
    {
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

   [Authorize]
    public ActionResult ViewMvovies()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ViewMovies(string dateFrom, string dateTo)
    {

        DateTime fromDate = DateTime.Parse(string.Format(dateFrom)).Date;
        DateTime toDate = DateTime.Parse(string.Format(dateTo)).Date;


        var movies = _context.Movies.ToList().Where(g => g.DateTime > fromDate && g.DateTime < toDate);

        return View("ViewMovies2");

    }
```

**My second View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<movies.Models.Movies>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "ViewMovies2";
}

<h2>Movie list</h2>

<ul class="movies">
@foreach (var movie in Model)
{
    <li>
        <div class="date">
            <div class="month">
                Month @movie.DateTime.ToString("MMM")
            </div>
            <div class="day">
                Day @movie.DateTime.ToString("d ")
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="details">
            <span class="category">
                Category @movie.Category.Name
            </span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="cost">
                Cost @movie.Cost
            </span>
        </div>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

The second View page is most likely incorrect, it's just something i tried to write, but it didn't work.

Error : 
    Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

In line :
(of the second View)

@foreach (var movie in Model)

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of error , you did not pass the model to view.

You can pass the model with that line.

```
return View("ViewMovies2" ,movies );
```

Comment: This worked, i guess i dont completely understand how Controller-View works, cause when i hovered over the View() method it didn't say anything about passing a model. Oh well, atleast it wasn't a big problem. Thanks!